# No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy construyendo un formulario para actualizar un registro, este se muestra correctamente y despues de rellenar los campos y hacer click en el submit da el siguiente error: No route matches [POST] "/articles/1".
La version de rails que tengo es la 7.0.2.3 y la version de ruby es la 3.1.1p18 y el so es windwos 10.
routes.rb

```rb
get 'articles/:id/edit' => 'articles#edit'
put 'articles/:id' => 'articles#update'
```

Controlador articles

```rb
def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    
    if @article.update(article_param)
        redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @article.id
    end
end

private def article_param
    params.permit(:title, :content)
end
```

El formulario

```rb
<%= form_for :posts_path, :url => { :action => :update, :id => @article.id }, :class => "w-25" do %>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <%= label_tag :title, nil, :class => "form-label" %><br>
        <%= text_field_tag :title, nil, :class => "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <%= label_tag :content, nil, :class => "form-label" %><br>
        <%= text_area_tag :content, nil, :class => "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <p>
        <%= submit_tag :Enviar %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: En el formulario también use :post en vez de :posts_path y también me sale el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás usando rails 7, deberías usar `form_with`, ya que `form_for` [estará obsoleto en siguientes versiones](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-form-tag-and-form-for).
Respecto al uso de PUT, siguiendo [la documentación de Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark), lo que deberías hacer es:

```
<%= form_with @article, url: article_path(@article), method: :put, :class => "w-25" do %>
```

Comment: Fue usar ```method: :put``` y dejar el resto igual y se soluciono todo, ahora ya puedo actualizar los registros. Para el próximo formulario que tenga que hacer tendré en cuenta el uso de form_with en versiones superiores a la 5.1